# Searching for a list in a list

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching

I want to see if a specific list is part of another list and get either `True` or `False`.

As an example:

```
list1={1,2,3,4}
list2={1,2}
list3={1,3}
```

list2 is now part of list1 and the argument should be `True`, while list3 isn't part of list1 as it is not the correct order.

I tried several Pattern Mactching Functions like `MemberQ`, which only works for elements not for lists.
`SubsetQ` is pretty close, but doesn't check the correct order as well as `ContainsX`.

My workaround is to convert the list into a string and use `StringContainsQ`, but I think there might be a better solution as well.

Comment: `SequenceCases[list1, #] & /@ {list2, list3}`

Comment: `inItQ[alist_,anotherlist_]:=MatchQ[alist,Join[{___},anotherlist,{___}]]` followed by `inItQ[list1,list2]` and `inItQ[list2,list3]`

Comment: Should l`list4={2,1}` give True or False?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
a = {1, 2, 3, 4};   
b = {1, 2};
c = {1, 3};
```

**1.**

Using `SequenceCases`

```
SequenceCases[a, b] == {b}
```

True

```
SequenceCases[a, c] == {c}
```

False

**2.**

Using `SequenceCount`

```
SequenceCount[a, #] > 0 & /@ {b, c}
```

{True, False}

**3.**

Using `Partition`

```
MemberQ[#] @ Partition[a, 2, 1] & /@ {b, c}
```

{True, False}

`Partition` should be significantly faster with long lists than one of the `Sequence`-functions

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear[f, g]

f[alist_?VectorQ, blist_?VectorQ] := 
 Subsequences[alist, {Length@blist}] // MemberQ[blist]

g = LongestCommonSubsequence[#1, #2] === #2 &;
```

---

Test:

```
list1 = {1, 2, 3, 4};
list2 = {1, 2};
list3 = {1, 3};
list4 = {1, 2, 3};

p = Permutations[{list1, list2, list3, list4}, {2}]

Transpose[{p, Apply[f, p, {1}]}] // Grid
```

[image]

---

Similarly: `Transpose[{p, g @@@ p}] // Grid`

Answer (score 3):

```
l1 = {1, 2, 3, 4};
l2 = {1, 2};
l3 = {1, 3};
```

---

Another way using `ReplaceList`:

```
patt = PatternSequence[##] &;

f = ReplaceList[#1, {___, s : patt @@ #2, ___} :> {s}] =!= {} &;

f @@ {l1, l2}

(*True*)

f @@ {l1, l3}

(*False*)
```

Or using `PositionIndex`:

```
f = Det@Differences@Lookup[PositionIndex[#1], #2] == 1 &;

f @@ {l1, l2}

(*True*)

f @@ {l1, l3}

(*False*)
```